# Remove space between bounds and button border

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

How do I remove those space between `Button` border and view bounds tried setting `padding` to `0dp` but with no results.
These is material button with default style.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is your button background drawable? a custom one?

Comment: Nope using Widget.MaterialComponents.Button Theme from Material Components Library

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: so check how it is defined - most likely your "padding" is made there

Comment: `<Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_link"
        style="@style/TextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/sign_in_link_label"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#555"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sign_up_btn" />`

Comment: uploaded another image need to remove spaces marked by black color

Comment: did you check `@style/TextButton`?

Comment: `<style name="TextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="rippleColor">#DDD</item>
    </style>`

Comment: and `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`?

Comment: for example `android:insetTop` and `android:insetBottom`? do you see such attrs inside `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button`?

Comment: Thank you very much it worked,a simple question could I use size in dp instead of wrap_content for height

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `MaterialButton` has a default style with these insets:

```
 <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"..>
    <item name="android:insetLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetTop">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset</item>
    ...
 </style>
```

The value of `@dimen/mtrl_btn_inset` is `6dp`.

Just use:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:insetTop="0dp"
      android:insetBottom="0dp"
      ../>
```

[image][image]

Comment: May I change the minHeight in styles to 36dp

Comment: @nabeel Yes. You can add in your style `<item name="android:minHeight">36dip</item>` or in your Button `android:minHeight="36dip"`. The default is `48dp`

Comment: The default uses insets and a 48dp min height because that is the minimum touch target size to make the button accessible for a majority of users. You could be making your app harder to use by making the height smaller. https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use weight and make the width 0dp then space will be removed.

Comment: b/w I'm using ConstraintLayout

Comment: ConstraintLayout will be your parent but if you want button in horizontal then you will need to use Linear layout and the button

Comment: In ConstraintLayout you can use this: layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf,layout_constraintBottom_toEndOf,app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf .

Comment: please check the other image I uploaded

Comment: did you used app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf, it used when you want first button parallel to the other